# Перетаскивание формы без заголовка по экрану

Tags: delphi, форма

Собственно встала задача перетаскивать форму без заголовка на форме расположен только webbrowser у него нету собития mousedown как можно решить такую проблему?

код

> ```
> ReleaseCapture;
> Perform(WM_SYSCOMMAND, $F012, 0);
> ```

в событие mousedown  формы не помогает, так как браузер занимает всю площадь формы...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примерно так. Т.е. перехватываем сообщения у приложения:

```
procedure TForm1.WndMessage(var Msg: TMsg; var Handled: Boolean);
const
  SC_DRAGMOVE:LongInt=$F012;
begin
  Handled:=false;
  if (Msg.Message = WM_LBUTTONDOWN)  then
  begin
    ReleaseCapture;
    Perform(wm_syscommand,SC_DRAGMOVE,0);
    Handled := True;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Application.OnMessage:=WndMessage;
end;
```

Comment: Спасибо! то что нужно!